# How to convert NSString to Float

Tags: ios, swift

```
IBAction func numberPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
  if isTyping == false {
    firstNumber = (sender.currentTitle as NSString).floatValue
    displayLabel.text = "\(firstNumber)"
  }
```

Showing error:

> Can not convert the expression's type '()' to type 'NSString'

Comment: What is the type of currentTitle?

Comment: `AnyObject` does not have `currentTitle` property by default I guess.

Comment: you are finally setting it as string only then why you want to convert to float?

Comment: I am making calculator app and want to add decimal point functionality so sender.currentTitle is trying to get number written on buttons so I can do operation on it. Need help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code sender is the anonymous type AnyObject. When you create an IBAction you have the option to change the type of Sender to the actual type of the control that triggers the action (usually a UIButton). I suggest changing the type of the sender to the correct type.

Failing that you will need to cast the type to your sender's type, which is a little bit risky.

```
let senderAsButton = sender as UIButton
```

That will crash at runtime of sender is not a UIButton. Thus it's better to fix the definition of the IBAction method signature.

### Edit:

Another issue is that the UIButton method currentTitle returns an optional. You have to unwrap it:

```
firstNumber = (sender.currentTitle! as NSString).floatValue
```

Note that that code will crash if sender.currentTitle is nil. It would be safer to write it like this:

```
if let currentTitle = sender.currentTitle as NSString
{
  firstNumber = currentTitle.floatValue
}
```

Comment: I have changed to UIButton, still the same error, any help

Comment: I edited my post. I don't understand why you are getting the message you are getting, but I do understand why it won't compile.

Comment: The `if let` form at the end of my post is safer than using the exclamation point. If you used an exclamation point to "force-unwrap" the optional you'll crash if it's nil.

Comment: Once again thank you. I learnt whole concept behind it. It worked for me